# How to install/start using swtpm on Linux

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, tpm

I am trying to start using TPM on Linux, on my Raspberry Pi to be accurate, and the easiest would be to use swtpm to get used to commands and system, before using a TPM chip. I've tried the way presented on https://github.com/stefanberger/swtpm/wiki#compile-on-ubuntu-2104, but I got the error "Unable to locate libtpms-dev".

Then I looked for a way to install libtpms, and found this one [solution](https://gist.github.com/racerxdl/26bc3f4bc443fa145b6f5604923d216f). But after getting those both, I still couldn't run this command :

```
sudo swtpm socket --tpmstate dir=/home/ludovic.peyter/swtpm  --tpm2 --server type=tcp,port=2321 --ctrl type=tcp,port=2322 --flags not-need-init,startup-clear
```

All I get is the following error :

```
swtpm: SWTPM_NVRAM_Lock_Dir: Could not open lockfile: No such file or directory
```

and

```
swtpm: Error: Could not initialize libtpms.
```

And here am I stuck, finding nothing to help me with this problem, or even an other way to avoid it.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a complete solution, built with many different solutions and my own tests.

```
sudo apt -y install dpkg-dev debhelper libssl-dev libtool net-tools libfuse-dev libglib2.0-dev libgmp-dev expect libtasn1-dev socat python3-twisted gnutls-dev gnutls-bin  libjson-glib-dev gawk git python3-setuptools softhsm2 libseccomp-dev automake autoconf libtool gcc build-essential libssl-dev dh-exec pkg-config dh-autoreconf libtool-bin tpm2-tools libtss0 libtss2-dev
```

Then make a new directory for more comfort, and step into it.

Clone git repository for libtpms :

```
git clone https://github.com/stefanberger/libtpms.git
```

Move to the generated libtpms directory and run these commands :

```
./autogen.sh -–with-openssl
make dist
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -j4
```

Then, as asked at the end of the last running command, run :

```
libtool --finish /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/
```

The directory could be different, so pay attention to the warning at the end of dpkg command.

And to finish the installation of libtpms :

```
sudo apt install ../libtpms*.deb
```

Now get back to the previous directory and clone swtpm git repository :

```
git clone https://github.com/stefanberger/swtpm.git
```

Now run this command :

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -j4
```

And the command asked by the previous running command :

```
libtool --finish /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/swtpm
```

The directory could be different, so pay attention to the warning at the end of dpkg command.

Now finish the installation with this :

```
sudo apt install ../swtpm*.deb
```

Everithing you need is installed. Now you need to modify the file ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile to add this line :

```
export TPM2TOOLS_TCTI="swtpm:port=2321"
```

And now, everytime you need your swtpm, open two terminals, and in one of them run :

```
swtpm socket --tpmstate dir=<swtpm_path> --tpm2 --server type=tcp,port=2321 --ctrl type=tcp,port=2322 --flags not-need-init,startup-clear
```

In the other terminal, as long as the above command runs, you can run all your TPM commands.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately, on Linux MX21  ./autogen.sh -–with-openssl fails after short work with sad error message: configure: error: unrecognized option: `-–with-openssl'. I presume some libs are still missing, but which one?

Comment: Thank you, this helped me install on Debian buster. Note to @piotao - there is an invalid "long" dash before with-openssl, just replace with short dash, i.e. --with-openssl

Comment: Yes, indeed, thank you. But I can't now recall if that was caused by typo or by wrong copy/paste or some other misinterpretation. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the tpmstate directory exists? A `mkdir /home/ludovic.peyter/swtpm2` could fix it for you.

Comment: This should just be a comment to the OP.

Comment: Actually, thanks to you I've seen that my directory is swtpm and not swtpm2... Copy/Paste I hate you. But the problem remains.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I thought the cmd line asks for a file to put its data in, but it actually requires a directory - just like `dir` implies -  and it now works, after creating the directory.